# (PHP/Laravel) Erro ao adicionar um segundo item no array, não incrementa a quantidade do segundo item

Tags: php, array

Meu Controller

```
public function Adicionar(Request $request) {
    $id_produto = $request->get('botao');
    $itens = $this->carrinho->getItens();
    //dd($itens);

    try{
        foreach($itens as $item){
            $est = Produto::find($id_produto);
            if($id_produto == null){
                return \Redirect::back()->with('mensagens-erro', 'Erro, Não há produto Selecionado');
            }elseif($item->produto->id != $id_produto){

                $this->carrinho->add($id_produto);
                return \Redirect::back()->with('mensagens-sucesso', 'Produto adicionado ao carrinho 1');    
            }else{
                if($item->produto->id == $id_produto){
                $item->qtde++;
                return \Redirect::back()->with('mensagens-sucesso', 'Produto adicionado ao carrinho 2'); 
                }
            }

        }   
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return redirect()->back()
       ->with('mensagens-erro', 'Erro!!!')
       ->withInput();
    }

    if($this->carrinho->add($id_produto)){   
        return \Redirect::back()->with('mensagens-sucesso', 'Produto adicionado ao carrinho');
    }else{
        return redirect()->back()
       ->with('mensagens-danger', 'Erro não é possivel adicionar Produto desejado')
       ->withInput();    
    }

}
```

Minha View

```
@extends('layouts.frente-loja')

@section('conteudo')

<br/>
<h2>Cardápio</h2>
@foreach($produto as $produto)

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">

    <div class="card h-100">
            <img style='height:300px; width:300px;' src="{{route('imagem.file',$produto->imagem_nome)}}" alt="">
            <div style='margin-bottom: 30px;' class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    {{$produto->nome}}
                </h4>
                <p class="card-text">{{str_limit($produto->descricao,100)}}</p>
                <h4 class="card-text">R${{$produto->preco_venda}}</h4>
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg getid" value='{{$produto->id}}' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Mais Detalhes</button>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
        <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class='conteudo'></p>
        <p class='valor'></p>
        <img style='height:200px; width:200px;' class="imagem" />
        <br/>
        <form class="action_carrinho"  action="{{route('adicionar')}}">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit" name="botao" value="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  pull-left add_carrinho" > Adicionar ao carrinho</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

        <!-- Modal carrinho -->
<div id="carrinho_id" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Carrinho</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Produto</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Preço Unitário</th>
                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($itens as $item)
                <tr class="teste">
                    <td>
                        <img src="{{route('imagem.file',$item->produto->imagem_nome)}}" alt="{{$item->produto->imagem_nome}}" data-lightbox="roadtrip" style="width:70px;" >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{route('produto.detalhes', $item->produto->id)}}">
                            {{$item->produto->nome}}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        {{number_format($item->produto->preco_venda, 2, ',', '.')}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center"> 
                        {{$item->qtde}}
                    </td>
                    <td> <a href="{{route('remover', $item->produto->id)}}" 
                            class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right">Excluir item </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-right">
                        Total
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h4 class="text-center text-danger">
                            R${{number_format($total,2,',','.')}}
                        </h4>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="submit" name="botao" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  pull-left add_carrinho" > Confirmar pedido</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="{{asset('bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers:{
            'X-CSRF-Token':$('input[name="_token"]').val()
        }
    });
        $('.getid').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/mesa/produto/'+id,
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(id) {
                $('.modal-title').html(id.nome);
                $('.conteudo').html(id.descricao);
                $('.valor').html('R$: '+id.preco_venda);
                $(".imagem").attr("src",'http://localhost:8000/imagem/arquivo/'+id.imagem_nome);
                $('.add_carrinho').val(id.id);
                //console.log($('.add_carrinho').val());
                console.log(id.id);
                },
            });

        });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

        $('.add_carrinho').click(function(){
            window.location.href =  "http://localhost:8000/finalizar_cardapio/";    

        });
});
</script>
@stop
```

Comment: Qual o PHP que voce utilizar? Essa funcao $this->certinho->getItens() como voce faz o setItens? Pois esse itens so existe nesse bloco de codigo. Ou seja e uma variavel local. Quando voce faz o redirect a mudanca do array nao e persistida no carinho

Comment: public function getItens() {
        return $this->itens;
    }